# How to recreate the iPhone app store application detail view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

I'm trying to get a view that is similar to the the application detail view presented in the app store but I can't figure out how it is implemented. It looks like a UITableView with 3 or 4 custom cells. Does that sound right? Any insight would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah it's not like that at all. What it is, is a couple of scrollviews (ie., the screenshots is just a scroll view tied to a paging control), directly above that is either a web view or a scroll view (hard to tell) -- with the actual content. Above the content you'll have a few items in the content view that holds everything, the app icon, name, company, etc. And at the very buttom, you can implement it as a table view if you want, but yes, you'll need custom cells, which isn't difficult to do, you just have to implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate, and return the appropriate height for each cell in that view, then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` switch on the indexPath's `row` property, and if it's one type of cell, set it up how you need to, if it's another, do that custom cell, etc.

It's not really hard at all. I reproduce a view similar to this in one app that I work on in the store, and I do it pretty much just as I described above.